# Delimiter occurring inside byte stream as actual data

Tags: tcp, byte, delimiter

Suppose you have a specification for sending information on a TCP or UDP stream and you have a sequence of bytes that you receive delimited with STX and EOT bytes. How do you handle for example the EOT byte occurring in the actual data? This is possible I think: most bytes in the message represent numbers in a defined order (i.e. it's not just ascii text in byte form) so EOT is byte 0x04 and this a number that could occur in the data. The specification is unclear on this: should I always look at the last occurrance of EOT and ignore those in between? Other similar specifications I've seen could even handle multiple messages inside the same TCP/UDP message: for example STX some_data EOT STX more_data EOT inside one TCP/UDP message. In this case you can't just look at the last EOT because it's actually 2 separate messages. Do you do some form of escaping then?

How is this sort of thing handled usually? I couldn't find anything on google, but perhaps I'm not using the best search terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Usually" the protocol should be well designed, so that messages either don't contain the delimiter, use an escape mechanism to include the delimiter, or have a known length so that you know where the message ends without having to depend on the delimiter.

If the messages are fixed size integers for example you'll know that EOT encountered within an integer is not a delimiter.